# Android flavors with different applicationId broke application behavior and look

Tags: android, android-flavors

I am using following `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def final appId = "com.example.app"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId appId
        buildConfigField "String", "DBNAME", "\"mydb.db\""
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        rel {
            minSdkVersion 14
            applicationId = "${appId}"
            buildConfigField "String", "DBNAME", "\"mydb.db\""
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 33
            versionName '1.4'
        }
        dev {
            minSdkVersion 14
            applicationId =  "${appId}.dev"
            buildConfigField "String", "DBNAME", "\"mydb_dev.db\""
            targetSdkVersion 3
            versionCode 1
            versionName '1.4-beta'

        }
    }
}

...
```

I have not copied code from `main` to `rel` and `dev` source sets, and I have just created separate files for each flavor: res/values/strings.xml, res/values/colors.xml, google-service.json.

The application builds well, with different `applicationId` and installs as separate on the same device.

For the `rel` flavor everything works well, and it has `applicationId = 'com.example.app'` equal to original package name and to actual source package name.

But I obtain very strange behavior and look for the `dev` flavor, which becomes `applicationId = 'com.example.app.dev'`

Firstly, I see that animations are not working properly, because it seems that they become wrong coordinates.

Secondary, I have many fragments with dynamically inflating views and they are showing partly or not showing at all - differently at different run.

I suggest that the issue is that I have the same package name for classes and probably there emerges so ambiguous class identification.

I see that getContext() returns the same class 'com.example.app.MainActivity' for both flavors and I think this is matter.

I wouldn't like to copy all sources under each source set because i don't need to make changes there - code still the same.

What is a solution?

Comment: So you created seperate folders with res subfolders for each flavor? Are you defining the folders as sourcesets somewhere in your build.gradle? 
Also: Did you read and understand how layout files are merged? See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging

Comment: I made changes in `build.gradle` and then ran gradle task android:sourceSets, and the I have created folders corresponding to declared in the `build.gradle` and placed here files with different resources definitions.
I see that builds for each flavor take resources properly: strings, colors and google services are different respectively and work. But the problem with behavior and view appear.

Comment: An yes, I have read about merging of resources

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistyping that kills many hours to resolve...

I had pointed `targetSdkVersion 3` rather `targetSdkVersion 23`

*(I am surprised that it was building at all)*

The Issue is solved, Android Flavors are magnificent!